# Compute this complex contour integral for two scenarios

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a problem where I have to calculate $I(r) := \int_{C[0,r]} \frac{dz}{z-a}$ for some fixed complex number $a$.

We split this up into two cases, namely when $r < |a|$ for which our path, in this case a circle centered at the origin with radius $r$, becomes null-homotopic, as well as the integrand is holomorphic in this region. We can apply Cauchy's theorem so that the integral becomes $0$ trivially.

Then for the second case, meaning $r > |a|$, we'll have to try and do a manual calculation in order to arrive at our solution. If we let our circle be parametrized with $re^{it}$ where $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, we have:

$$ \int_{C[0,r]} \frac{dz}{z-a} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ire^ {it}}{re^ {it}-a}dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ire^ {it}}{r^2+|a|^2}(re^{-it}-\bar{a})dt=$$

$$ = i \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r^2}{r^2+|a|^2}dt-i\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\bar{a}re^{it}}{r^2+|a|^2}dt =  \frac{2\pi ir^2}{r^2+|a|^2}$$ but the solutions tell me that it should be $2\pi i$ and I can't see where I do anything wrong really. Thank you for any help!

Comment: why do you think that $|re^ {it}-a|^2=r^2+|a|^2$?  (hint: there is a $\cos t$ term in there)

Comment: Oh now I see what went wrong. I was confused thinking that $x+iy$ was in the denominator. I'm thinking that I can split the integral up in $\int_{0}^{2\pi} i dt + \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ai}{re^{it}-a} dt$ now only showing that the latter has to be 0 since the answer is $2\pi i$ equaling the first integral. But I don't really see any smart way to show that.

Comment: Use a geometric series for the denominator

Comment: Use a second application of Cauchy's theorem to replace the circle about $0$ with a small circle about $a$. Then a change of variable to remove $a$ from the integral entirely.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Doesn't the integrand have to be holomorphic on our region in order to apply Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic on the region inside the larger circle about $0$ but outside the smaller circle about $a$. Its only singularity is inside the smaller circle. By Cauchy's theorem, the difference of the two integrals is $0$. (It is the difference because when considering the two circles as the boundary of the region, the inner circle is integrated in the reverse direction). If you want a simply connected region of integration, draw a line connecting the two circles. This line will be on the boundary of the region twice, integrated in opposite directions, so it contributes 0 overall

Comment: @PaulSinclair So we are basically just setting our second path to be $\mathbb{C}\ C[a,\epsilon]$ for some small radius $\epsilon > 0$, which thus keeps our function holomorphic on the complex plane except that point, and since $C[0,r] \sim_\mathbb{C} C[a,\epsilon]$, we can just reduce the integral to contour integration along $ C[a,\epsilon]$ using Cauchy's theorem and then use the substitution you already stated. Am I in the right now?

Comment: Yes. It is a standard technique, and how one later proves the Residue Theorem. Once you've centered the integral about $a$, the problem simplifies considerably.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Okay nice I'm really looking forward to that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma$ is a loop, $\Omega=int(\gamma)$ and $f\in H(\Omega)\cap\mathcal C(\overline{\Omega})\implies$ $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw, \hspace{0.5cm}\forall z\in \Omega.$$
In your case you have $f(z)\equiv 1$, $\forall z\in\mathbb C$. The curve along which you are interating is $\gamma =\partial D_r(0)$.
The integrand $h_a(z)=1/(z-a)$, with $a\in\mathbb C$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C\setminus\{a\}$.

If $|a|>r\implies a\notin\overline{D_r(0)}$ so you are integrating the function along the boundary of a region in which $h_a$ is holomorphic so $I_r=0$.

If $|a|<r$ you can see the problem like this: Let $0<\zeta<dist(a,\partial D_r(0))$ and consider the region with multiple boundary $\Omega$ such that $\partial \Omega=\partial D_r(0)-\partial D_{\zeta}(a)\implies$
$$\int_{\partial \Omega}h_a=0=\int_{\partial D_r(0)}h_a-\int_{D_{\zeta}(a)}h_a$$
but, for Cauchy theorem, $\int_{\partial D_{\zeta}(a)}h_a(w)dw=\int_{\partial D_{\zeta}(a)}f(w)/(w-a)dw=2\pi if(a)=2\pi i\cdot 1$ and in conclusion
$$I_r=\int_{\partial D_{\zeta}(a)}h_a=2\pi i.$$

Comment: Except that the calculation Tanamas is doing is part of the proof of Cauchy's integral formula, and thus it is not kosher to use that formula to obtain it.